# CSS: drop-down causes page to jump up

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

When user clicks on my drop-down menu, it jumps the page back to the very top (like a page reload).

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3837z3b0/2/) with stripped down code.

I know that if I remove the `#` in `href="#"`, it should work, but that is not good practice.

How do I make it so it doesn't jump the page to top?

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Drop</a>

            <ul class="nav-user nav-li-cont">
                <li><a href="/"> Hello </a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="/"> World </a>

                </li>
            </ul>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.nav {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:50px;
}
div.nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;        
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}

div.nav ul li {
    float:left;
}

div.nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.nav ul li ul { 
    display:none;
}

div.nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: list-item;
    position: absolute;
}


div.nav ul li:hover ul li {
    float:none;
}

div.nav ul li ul li:hover {
    float:none;
}

div.nav ul li ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}

.nav-li-cont {
    border-radius: 4px;
    float: left !important;
    padding: 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: I'm having difficulty observing the behavior you report on your jsfiddle using my android device. Perhaps the problem is that the demo page is too short to see the jumping to the top effect?

Comment: @DavidRoundy It appears that this problem is not just related to mobile browsers, but all browsers. See the updated fiddle where you can scroll down the page and test: http://jsfiddle.net/3837z3b0/2/

Comment: I'm trying to clarify what you're looking for, so I moved the menu down and adjusted the links. Nothing happens (as expected), so is this what you're looking for, or is it something different: http://jsfiddle.net/jn0p53d0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because there's no js/jquery assigned to that link. And the browser will assume that this is a "link for a new page", and actually if you check the URL of the website, it's propably changed to this after you click on that button (you can't see this on jsfiddle): `example.com/currentPage/#`.

If you change this line

```
<a href="#">Drop</a>
```

to this instead

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Drop</a>
```

it will not jump to the top anymore. [The void operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) is often used merely to obtain the `undefined` primitive value (which is equivalent to “`void 0`”). In these cases, the global variable undefined can be used instead (assuming it has not been assigned to a non-default value).

http://jsfiddle.net/3837z3b0/3/

---

### Update

If you have multiple links using `href="#"` you can either exchange the links as I mentioned above to this `href="javascript:void(0)"` or you can add a class called `noclick` for example for every link that has `href="#"` and add the following:

```
$(".noClick").attr('href','javascript:void(0)');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3837z3b0/4/

Comment: Very nice! I have multiple a tags with href="#" which I need to target. Is there a way to add the void(0) inside my JS file and target these links appropriately?